# npm get prefix: command not found

Tags: node.js, command-line, terminal

Trying to install firebase on the command line, can't do it because I probably need to change npm permissions. Problem is, when I run "npm get prefix" it comes back with "command not found". I know I have node.js, npm, git and bower installed, but I am very new to the command line and can't find anything online that references this. Can anyone help? Using Mac OSX.

Comment: what do you get if you write `npm --version` inside your command line ? are you using windows, linux or macos ?

Comment: npm probably isn't in your search path.  You may need to restart your terminal or update `PATH`.

Comment: @sheplu same, command not found. Weird, I have no idea whats going on. I will try that SLks.

Comment: so npm is not installed in your system, or at least your command line doesn't know it. Like @SLaks said, you shoud try to restart your cli. If it doesn't work, try installing npm again (should be packaged with node)

Comment: Thank you, but I tried quitting the terminal numerous times, nothing changed. I will try re-installing npm.

Comment: Re-installing node.js worked. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I should specify what was going on here: I tried re-installing node.js a few times and it didn't work. I was re-installing the most recent version and for some reason my terminal didn't see it. The problem was fixed when I installed the LTS (Long Term Support) version.